# Can You Level Up Guns To Match Your Power Level In Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

I am around power level 820 in Destiny 2. I was thinking of doing some exotic quests. These guns would drop a bit above my power level and as I progressed they would become obsolete. In the future if I want to can I match the guns power level to mine so I can use it again?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you're a way off max level cap right now so you may want to consider doing more of the core content before you complete the exotic quests. The reason for that is at level 820 you'll be picking up rare and legendary gear regularly that boosts your level. When you get to higher levels you'll find the blues don't help with your level progression anymore. When that happens, picking up an exotic that's a bit above your power level will be a bit more valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can by infusing guns into your exotics you will sacrifice the higher power weapon to bring the exotic weapon up to match its power level.

To do this hit details on any weapon and hover over the first tile to see a list of weapons available to use for infusion.

You can only infuse wepons of the same catagory.

Comment: Category meaning kinetic, energy, or power.  The actual weapon type or which ammo it uses does not matter for infusion.

Comment: Thank You, I was a bit confused on what he meant.